# List not callabe inside a menu

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and I don't know why I am getting this error message, but this is the code I am working on:

```
txt_historico = "historico.txt"
HistoricoVendas = []
if exists(txt_historico):
    with open(txt_historico, "r") as arquivo_historico:
      HistoricoVendas = []

def imprimeHistorico()
  print()
  if len[HistoricoVendas] > 0:
    print(HistoricoVendas)
  else: 
      print("Não há histórico de vendas por enquanto")

elif ans=="6":
  HistoricoVendas()
```

I only put the parts where this specific mistake happens, but if it helps I can post the whole code no problem.

Is the error in the way I am naming that HistoricoVendas ?

Comment: What's your error? Could you show us?

Comment: This is not the proper way to check length: len[HistoricoVendas] you should use this : len(HistoricoVendas)

Comment: Yes, sorry I believe I didn't specify it that well, I get the error message "type error: 'list' object is not callable", regarding HistoricoVendas()

Answer (score 0):

As Muhammad hassan says in the comment, you can't do this: `len[something]`. It should be like this: `len(something)`.

Also you can't separate `elif` and `if` statements.

```
# You can do whatever you want before going into the if statement
txt_historico = "historico.txt"
HistoricoVendas = []
if exists(txt_historico):
    with open(txt_historico, "r") as arquivo_historico:
      HistoricoVendas = []

if exists(txt_historico):
    with open(txt_historico, "r") as arquivo_historico:
      HistoricoVendas = []
# You can't insert code here
elif ans=="6":
  HistoricoVendas()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply ! I should just have posted the whole code so it makes more sense: